# Can I make JSLint interpret .toBeDefined as a null check when testing with typescript?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vitest

My tests are riddled with TS18047 warnings.

My code usually goes like this:

```
expect(myVar).toBeDefined();  // or .not.toBeNull()
expect(myVar.id).toEqual(1); // <<-- TS18047
expect(myVar.title).toEqual('test'); // <<-- TS18047
```

There are two "easy" solutions that I could figure out, but they both introduce unnecessary code:

Solution 1:

```
expect(myVar).toBeDefined();
expect(myVar?.id).toEqual(1);
expect(myVar?.title).toEqual('test');
```

Solution 2:

```
expect(myVar).toBeDefined();
if (myVar != null) {
  expect(myVar.id).toEqual(1);
  expect(myVar.title).toEqual('test');
}
```

But I feel JSLint should be able to interpret .toBeDefined() equal to null check.

Shouldn't it?

Can I make it do so?